# Cheapest yet safest solution to measure AC lines? (1 phase as well as 3 phase)

Tags: sensor, ac

Any solution apart from using hall effect sensor to measure current through AC lines? The value measured will be later processed by a MCU.

Comment: What's wrong with hall effect sensors? It's most obvious way.

Comment: Adding those sensors just ramp up my over all cost. Imagine 52 lines, so you say use 52 sensors?

Comment: Yes :) there are those HE sensors without the conductor, with pcb trace underneath. Maybe they are cheaper.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a current transformer.

Comment: How much would it cost approx?

Comment: If you want to measure usual currents (less then 10Amps for example), you can use an inexpensive CT. Take a look at Digikey ou Mouser, they have a lot of them.

Comment: That would do good for low current applications, what about 3-phase appliances like an air conditioner?

Comment: Yes I think. It is most used for higher currents. But it's suitable for lower currents as well. All depends on the accuracy wanted.

Comment: Will any of this do?[link](http://www.winson.com.tw/products_e_current_sensor.html)

Comment: These are hall effect sensors, not current transformers. But they ca be used anyway.

Comment: Yeah I just wanted the "cheapest" and "safest" these seem to fit into that category.